# How does is-invalid bootstrap class work?

Tags: html, vue.js, bootstrap-4

I have an input, which works correctly: after errror was returned from server to client, I see `{{value}}`.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-8 control-label">Foo</label>
    <input class="form-control" v-model="foo" :class="{' is-invalid': errors.foo}">
    <div class="invalid-feedback" v-if="errors.foo">
        <strong v-for="value in errors.foo">{{value}}</strong>
    </div>
</div>
```

So I guess, `div` with `class="invalid-feedback"` goes from `display: none` to `display: block` **only when** `div` which has `class="invalid-feedback"` **is on the same DOM level** with `<input class="form-control is-invalid">`.

```
<div>
    <input class="form-control" :class="{' is-invalid': errors.foo}">
    <div class="invalid-feedback" v-if="errors.foo">
        <!-- this example would work -->
    </div>
</div>
```

---

```
<div>
    <input class="form-control" :class="{' is-invalid': errors.foo}">
</div>
<div>
    <div class="invalid-feedback" v-if="errors.foo">
        <!-- this example would not work
             because error div isn't on the same DOM level with input -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Am I right? Didn't found anything in [docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/?#how-it-works) about DOM.

If yes, what workaround is suitable for case when I want show error inside `div` with `class="invalid-feedback"`, but "connected" input isn't on the same DOM level? Actually I want to make my 2nd example work.

**UPDATE:** I can add some `<div class="form-control" :class="{' is-invalid': errors.foo}" style="display: none;">` on the same DOM level where `<div class="invalid-feedback">` is, but it'd be spaghetti code.

Comment: I don't understand. Can you clarify the question? Did you [read the validation section in the docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/#how-it-works)?

Comment: @ZimSystem I have a Vue component with form. There is a non-html tag inside form which is used for cropping images. That tag render some `<canvas>`, `<input>` and other elements. I want to show error when user tries to submit form without image attached. I tried to add `class="form-control" :class="{' is-invalid': errors.foo}"` on my input, but error inside `<div class="invalid-feedback" v-if="errors.foo">` doesn't show anyway

Comment: @ZimSystem [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8vvjbvfg/4/)

Comment: If it doesn't show up, what's the value `errors.screenshot`?

Comment: @EmileBergeron it's a string. But anyway `div` with `invalid-feedback` doesn't want go "visible".

Comment: I think that's where a parent with `.was-validated` is necessary.

Comment: @EmileBergeron I'm trying at the moment. But I have a text input near like [that](https://jsfiddle.net/f78ydLoc/) and it works without adding `.was-validated`...

Comment: You're right, there is a placement requirement when placing the feedback div. I updated my answer with additional info

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using `v-if="errors.foo"` on the `invalid-feedback` div, so it will be inserted in the DOM only when `errors.foo` is *truthy*, *regardless of where it is in the DOM*.

As for the styling:

> HTML form validation is applied via CSS’s two pseudo-classes, `:invalid` and `:valid`. It applies to `<input>`, `<select>`, and `<textarea>` elements.

So the placement of the `.invalid-feedback` div is important **when using the default behaviour**, which applies the styling with the [general sibling combinator `~`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors)

```css
.was-validated .form-control:invalid~.invalid-feedback {/*...*/}
```

There is a `.was-validated` class that you should add on a parent element which will apply the error styling on invalid elements.

```
<div :class="{'was-validated': errors.foo}">
    <input class="form-control" :class="{' is-invalid': errors.foo}">
</div>
...
<div :class="{'was-validated': errors.foo}">
    <div class="invalid-feedback" v-show="errors.foo">...</div>
</div>
```

Since it must be a general sibling, you could force the `display: block` with **`v-show` or use custom CSS like [`d-block`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/display/).**

> As a fallback, `.is-invalid` and `.is-valid` classes may be used instead of the pseudo-classes for server side validation. **They do not require a `.was-validated` parent class.**

This is a known problem with [`.input-group` discussed in an issue](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/23454).

---

If you find it's starting to get messy, you can evaluate the possibility of wrapping the inputs in components which applies your styling and then just reuse your components.

Or you could use a Vue wrapper of bootstrap, like [bootstrap-vue](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/).

Comment: Yeah, one way to achieve this yet is to add `d-block` to `invalid-feedback`. Just leave [this link](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/23454) for future visitors. Make `has-error` great again.